# Как выгружать с сайта данные, вложенные в ячейку?

Tags: python, selenium

Я в первый раз пользуюсь selenium, а мне надо выгрузить сайт с электронными описями архивов. А именно я не смог разобраться с тем, как писать цикл, чтобы выгрузить не только 31 страницу с названиями фондов, но и все описи, которые хранятся внутри каждой из ячеек. К сожалению, привожу только самую начальную часть кода.

```
from selenium import webdriver as wb
br = wb.Chrome("/Users/YOUR_PATH_TO_DRIVER")
br.get("http://opisi.rgvarchive.ru/opisi.html")
####
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(br.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(html_soup)
####
#увеличение кол-ва ячеек на странице
br.find_element_by_class_name("dataTables_length").click()
br.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="example_length"]/label/select/option[4]').click()
####
#перелистывание
br.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="example_next"]').click()
#раскрытие первой ячейки фонда
br.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выгружать данные из таблиц, вложенных в ячейки с описью, можно как обычные html таблицы через BeatifulSoup, предварительно развернув с Selenium. Алгоритм:

1. сохранить вектор, содержащий объекты "Просмотр описи", чтобы итерировать по элементам вектора. При обращении `.click()` к первому элементу вектора появится интерактивная таблица, которую нужно дополнительно пролистывать также с помощью Selenium. *Особенность просмотра описей*: перед открытием новой вложенной в опись таблички необходимо закрыть предыдущую.
2. выкачать данные с BeautifulSoup можно по строкам таблицы (`tr` тэг), обратившись к текстовым ячейкам (`td` тэг). [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966368/python-beautifulsoup-scrape-tables) приведен пример парсинга таблички.
3. пролистать интерактивную таблицу, нажав на "Следующая". Повторить пункт 2.

Драфт кода, вытаскивающий строковые переменные первой интерактивной таблицы:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = wb.Chrome("/Users/YOUR_PATH_TO_DRIVER")
br.get("http://opisi.rgvarchive.ru/opisi.html")

################# ШАГ 1 ####################
# объект "следующая страница" для всего сайта
next_page = br.find_element_by_css_selector("#example_next")
# объект "следующая страница" для интерактивных таблиц
next_details = br.find_element_by_css_selector("#tbl_next")

# сохранить вектор с объектами "Просмотр описи" для первой страницы
details = br.find_elements_by_class_name(" details-control")

# первые два элемента вектора 'details' содержат ненужные объекты вне tbody
details[2].click() # открыть первую интерактвную таблицу

################# ШАГ 2 ####################
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.page_source) 
table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'tbl'})
for tr in table.findAll('tr'):
    row = tr.find_all('td')
    row[0].text # номер в таблице
    row[1].text # название дела
    row[2].text # даты
    row[3].text # номер страницы


################# ШАГ 3 ####################
next_details.click() # открыть вторую страницу первой интерактивной таблицы

# ... перед переходом к скрейпингу второй интерактивной таблицы
details[2].click() # закрыть первую таблицу
```

Разумно предварительно увеличиватьть количество показываемых строк как в интерактивных таблицах, так и на основных страницах с описями, что Вы уже реализовали в коде. Судя по коду сайта, `next_details` одинаков для всех интерактивных таблиц.